# Laplace transform of $\sin^2(\omega t)$

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

What is the Laplace transform of the function $\sin^2(\omega t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it as $$\frac{1-\cos 2\omega t}2$$ and apply the linearity property individually for each term.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\left[\sin^2\omega t\right]&=\mathcal{L}\left[\frac{1-\cos2\omega t}{2}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{L}\left[1\right]-\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{L}\left[\cos2\omega t\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{s}{s^2+(2\omega)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2s}\left(\frac{4\omega^2}{s^2+4\omega^2}\right).
\end{align}
$$